Where to annotate python variables?
As I understand it, variables in Python work the same way as in Java. That is, when assigning, we bind a reference to the object to the right of the assignment to the variable (name) x in the current scope. But in Java, names have definitions, unlike Python. And in this place, the type is specified. I understand that Python is initially an untyped language, but now it has type annotations, and there are also type checkers (even if they are not part of the language). Which type annotation do they consider correct. I can write
def h():
    if random.random() >= 0.5:
        v: str = input()
    else:
        v: int = 3
    f(v)  # type of v - ???

What is the variable annotation convention in Python?

Java has declarations which Python lacks. Python variables simply come into existence on their first definition.

Type hints are static, which means v cannot have a different static type depending on which branch of the if statement executes. The best you can do is to annotate v first, then try to use type-narrowing later.
def h():
    v: str | int
    if random.random() >= 0.5:
        v = input()
    else:
        v = 3
    f(v)  # Legal if f accepts an argument of type str | int

At runtime, of course, there is no problem. The static type of v only matters to tools like mypy.

At runtime, of course, there is no problem. - Other than the fact that having a variable that conditionally changes types is often a code smell.

Okay, thanks. I'll assume that from a typings point of view, the code is correct only if all annotations describe the same type. It's probably even better to assume that variables must have exactly one annotation if the Python type system allows different complex ways to describe the same set of values ​​(that is, it is clear that int | str and str | int are different types describing the same set of values, but maybe there are examples that cannot be automatically checked for equivalence)

@0x5453 THere's no change of types here, only dynamic choice of type that is modeled statically with a union type. (I'm not disagreeing that it's likely better for the branches to agree on a type for v, but I think this issue is beyond the scope of the question.)
